# writing condition for list1.contains(list2) in drools

Tags: drools, drools-flow

I gave pojos like

`Customer{
   List<String> groups;
}`

```
Master{
   List<String> groups;
}
```

I want to check conditions like

```
master1.groups.containsAny(customer1.groups);
```

and also

```
master1.groups.containsAll(customer1.groups);
```

How can i write drools condition for these two?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a List.containsAll method. For containsAny, you may have to write a static method or a DRL function.

Answer (score 0):

Use below Drools functions

```
function boolean containsAny(List<String> sourceList, List<String> targetList){
    sourceList.retainAll(targetList);
    return sourceList.size() != 0;
}
function boolean containsAll(List<String> sourceList, List<String> targetList){
    int size = sourceList.size();
    sourceList.retainAll(targetList);
    return sourceList.size() == size;
}
```